# C# assy in Powershell - calling contructor with enum params defined within the class

Tags: powershell

It seems that the problem I'm having hasn't been covered in any topic, or at least
I didn't find any yet.

I'm trying to use a C# assembly in which the constructor expects a enumerator type parameter
that is also defined within the class.

```
    namespace Utils.Translate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts ASCII to EBCDIC or vice-versa
    /// </summary>
    public class AsciiEbcdic
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// The enumerator CharSet2Use determines which target character set to use.
       /// </summary>
       public enum CharSet2Use 
       {
          A2E = 0,          //ASCII to EBCDIC
          E2A               // EBCDIC to ASCII
       };

       // Constructor
       public AsciiEbcdic( CharSet2Use whichSet )
       {
       }
    }
}
```

No problem loading the assembly:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile( "EbcdicAscii.dll" )
```

However, when I try to instantiate it, with

```
$nameSpace = "Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii"

$var = New-Object $nameSpace( [Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii+Char2Set2Use]::A2E )
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to find type [Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii+Char2Set2Use]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I also tried the following:

```
$var = New-Object $nameSpace -ArgumentList [Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii+Char2Set2Use]::A2E
```

I get the error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Also tried passing the parameter as A2E, 'A2E', 0, '0' to no avail.

Is there any way to instantiate this object passing an enumerator data type defined within the class?

Answer (score 2):

You have some typo in your code (class name and enum type name):
After `add-Type` :

you have written:

```
$nameSpace = "Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii"
$var = New-Object $nameSpace( [Utils.Translate.EbcdicAscii+Char2Set2Use]::A2E )
```

but it's this:

```
$nameSpace = "Utils.Translate.AsciiEbcdic"
$var = New-Object $nameSpace( [Utils.Translate.AsciiEbcdic+CharSet2Use]::A2E )
```

or

```
$var = New-Object $nameSpace -ArgumentList A2E 

$var
Utils.Translate.AsciiEbcdic
```

Comment: OMG, how embarassing. I've looked at the source code so long I just completely missed it. This proves that having someone check you code is really helpfull. Thanks a million, C.B.

Comment: @VagaBond Glad to help! You can accept my answer and those in other to your questions to be a good SO user ;)